# What is run_prettify.js?

Tags: javascript

What is run_prettify.js? Why it is used? I have seen many developer use this from Google CDN.
I searched this in google  but I did not get much info. I want to know details about it.

Comment: Are you *sure* you didn't get much info from searching?

Comment: First hit in my search engine for `run_prettify.js`: https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Comment: Please read this Doc: https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: As @FelixKling points out, this stackoverflow page is the #1 organic google result for `run_prettify.js` ... hopefully OP does not keep getting downvoted for simply asking what the file is. Many sites include the file and I didn't know what it was either, so I typed it into google.

Answer (score 2):

> Waht is run_prettify.js?

*A Javascript module [...] that allows syntax highlighting of source code snippets in an html page.* [[source]](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)

> Why it is used?

Because people want to syntax highlight source code.

Answer (score 2):

`run_prettify.js`
Is an embeddable script that makes source-code snippets in HTML prettier.

Here you can learn [how to use](https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html)

Answer (score 2):

But, now `run_prettify.js` was removed by google.

So, you can use this CDN version of this [cloudfare link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/run_prettify.js)

Answer (score 0):

run_prettify

> run_prettify adds styles to code snippets so that token boundaries stand out and your readers can get the gist of your code without having to mentally perform a left-to-right parse.

You can include run_prettify as given below

```
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

> it will load the entire system and schedule the prettifier to run on page load
>
> **with the use** of run_prettify our code looks great and easy readable.

[See More details for how it's works](https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html)